# mySQL Order by Most Commented and Least Commented

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to order a list of items based on the amount of comments for each topic as shown below:

```
$page = $_GET['page'];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM topic WHERE cat_id='$page' LIMIT $start, $per_page");

if (mysql_num_rows($query)>=1)
{
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
$number = $rows['topic_id'];
$title = $rows['topic_title'];
$description = $rows['topic_description'];

//get topic total
$sqlcomment = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE topic_id='$number'");
$commentnumber = mysql_num_rows($sqlcomment);
// TRYING TO ORDER OUTPUT ECHO BY TOPIC TOTAL ASC OR DESC
echo "
<ul>
<li><h4>$number. $title</h4>
<p>$description</p>
<p>$topictime</p>
<p>$commentnumber</p>
</li>
</ul>
";
}
}
else
{
echo "<p>no records available.</p><br>";
}
```

What would be the best way to order each echo by $num_rows (ASC/DESC values)? NOTE: I've updated with the full code - I am trying to order the output by $commentnumber

Comment: Have you tried using [`ORDER BY col ASC/DESC`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html) in the query?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this as the $num_rows comes after the $sql statement. Ideally, I would like to have $sql = "SELECT * FROM 'table' WHERE 'id' = '$id' ORDER BY $num_rows ASC"; but this would not work with the current structure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first query should be:

```
SELECT t.*, COUNT(c.topic_id) AS count
FROM topic AS t
LEFT JOIN comments AS c ON c.topic_id = t.topic_id
WHERE t.cat_id = '$page'
GROUP BY t.topic_id
ORDER BY count
LIMIT $start, $per_page
```

You can get `$commentnumber` with:

```
$commentnumber = $rows['count'];
```

You don't need the second query at all.

Comment: Maybe change `SELECT table.id` into `SELECT table.id, count(*) as count` , to be able to show `$row['count']`

Comment: This is the statement I have for $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM topic WHERE cat_id='$page' LIMIT $start, $per_page"); I am trying to display all the topics for a category which is equal to the URL using the $page. There is also pagination which is why there is a LIMIT. I would like to order each topic by the number of comments (most commmented and least commented) - I'm new to mySQL and not sure how to write the statement for this

Comment: Just to note, $result = mysql_query($sql); $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result); displays the number of topics in each echo using the original statement - the comments table is linked to the topics table using topic_id

Comment: The topic_id is a foriegn key in the comments table. I have three tables: category, topics, and comments. In psuedo, I am trying to count all the comments for each topic_id and order each echo by either ASC or DESC based on the comments count

Comment: I've updated the query to show the actual tables and columns as best I can guess, since you haven't shown details of the second query.

Comment: I've updated the question with the full code/issue which I am still experiencing

Comment: This has worked with ordering the topics but it only displays topics that have comments, how do I display topics without comments? e.g. all topics where the cat_id='$page'

Comment: Changed it to a LEFT JOIN to get topics with no comments. Note also that `COUNT(*)` also has to change to `COUNT(c.topic_id)` so that the rows with null matches count as 0 rather than 1.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have error here

```
echo "divs in order from least to greatest "number = $num_rows"";
```

It should be

```
echo "divs in order from least to greatest number = " . $num_rows . "";
```

And about the most commented try with

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` = '$id' ORDER BY column DESC/ASC";
```

Or if there is not count column try with

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` = '$id' ORDER BY COUNT(column) DESC/ASC";
```